# AWS Scalability methods for a WebSockets server

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability

I've been doing some server architecture design over the past few weeks and have run into an issue that I need outside help with. I'm creating a game server for a massively multiplayer game, so I need to receive constant updates on entity locations, then broadcast them out to relevant clients.

I've written servers with scale in mind before, but they were stateless servers, so it wasn't all that difficult. If I'm deploying this server on a cloud platform like Google Cloud or AWS, is it better to simple scale the instance that the server is running on, or should I opt for the reverse proxy method and deploy the server across multiple instances?

Sorry if this is a vague question. I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start here -

https://aws.amazon.com/gaming/

https://aws.amazon.com/gaming/game-server/

You also should consider messaging solutions such as SNS and SQS. If the app can receive push notifications then SNS might be your best option.

Comment: Neat, let me take a look into this! I've never seen this before.

Comment: Great, let me know how else I can help.